# Cronos Job - Issue when Weekend happens to be first day of the month

Tags: syntax, cron, cron-task

I am having troubles getting the syntax for a cronmask job right.

I am trying to run a script on both the first and second weekday of the month. While the first weekday is fine ( [0 0 1W * *] as in nearest weekday to 1st of month), I can't find a solution for the second weekday. 2W only works if the 1st falls within the Mon-Thu range. Otherwise 1W and 2W will be mapped to the same day. Does somebody have a solution for that? This would be an awesome feature to have.

Thanks and best regards